# How to prevent child event from firing in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, chaining, preventdefault

So  i have a button

```
<input id="expandButton" type="submit" value="Expand" class="loadWindow"/>
```

I have two event handler attached.

```
function confirmContinue() {
     return confirm("Do you want to expand window, might reload some information?");
}

$("input.loadWindow").click(function(event) {
      showProcessingWindow(event);
}

$("#expandButton").click(function(event) {
     var result = confirmContinue();
     if (!result) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagaton();
     }
}
```

I want to prevent "input.loadWindow" click event from firing if they say cancel.

This is what is happening right now. 
Button clicked --> Confirmation fire --> I click cancel --> show processing window still fires.

I want it so that
Button clicked --> Confirmation fire --> i click cancel --> do nothing.

Comment: Why you are having two separate event handlers for same element ? That way it will complicate things. If you want to show confirmation only for paticular ID, you can check the id of current click event using `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: the script is in two different files. 

One script loadWindow is in all the pages.

The other one is specific only to some page.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I have posted an answer. That should work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **[event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)** would work in this case.

```
$("#expandButton").click(function(event) {
     var result = confirmContinue();
     if (!result) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
     }
}
```

***Fiddle demo-*** http://jsfiddle.net/w2vwn35x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#expandButton").click(function(event) {
    if(confirm('Do you want to expand window, might reload some information?')){
        // call your function here
    }else{
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="expandButton" type="submit" value="Expand" class="loadWindow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a flag.

```
var doShowWindow = true;
$("#expandButton").click(function(event) {
    var result = confirmContinue();
    if (!result) {
        doShowWindow = false;
    }
});

$("input.loadWindow").click(function(event) {
    if(doShowWindow){  
        alert(1);
    }
    doShowWindow = true;
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/h54avw3y/1/).